# Parallel code runs slower than serial code

Tags: c, openmp, arm64

The following code calculates a dot product of 2 vectors.

- First vector: Complex `int16_t`
- Second vector: Complex `float`
- Output: Complex `float`

```
typedef struct ComplexInt16
{
    int16_t Re;
    int16_t Im;
}ComplexInt16;

typedef struct ComplexFloat
{
    float Re;
    float Im;
}ComplexFloat;

void ScalarMultiply(ComplexInt16 *In, ComplexFloat *Ref, ComplexFloat *Out, uint32_t N)
{
    ComplexInt16 *pIn = In;
    ComplexFloat *pRef = Ref;
    ComplexFloat *pOut = Out;

    int16x4x2_t     VecIn;
    float32x4x2_t   VecRef;
    float32x4x2_t   VecRes;

    float32x4x2_t Res;
    int16x4_t ReIn, ImIn;
    float32x4_t ReRef, ImRef, ReInf32;
    float32x4_t ReRes, ImRes, ImInf32;

    for (int i = 0; i < N >> 2; i++)
    {
        VecIn = vld2_s16((int16_t *)pIn);  //val[0]=1,3,5,7  val[1]=2,4,6,8 
        VecRef = vld2q_f32((float*)pRef);

        ReIn = VecIn.val[0];
        ImIn = VecIn.val[1];

        ReRef = VecRef.val[0];
        ImRef = VecRef.val[1];

        ReInf32 = vcvtq_f32_s32(vmovl_s16(ReIn));
        ImInf32 = vcvtq_f32_s32(vmovl_s16(ImIn));

        Res.val[0] = vsubq_f32(
            vmulq_f32(ReInf32, ReRef),
            vmulq_f32(ImInf32, ImRef));

        Res.val[1] = vaddq_f32(
            vmulq_f32(ImInf32, ReRef),
            vmulq_f32(ReInf32, ImRef));

        //Store in destination
        vst2q_f32((float*)pOut, Res);

        pIn += 4;
        pRef += 4;
        pOut += 4;
    }
}
```

In order to run this code on all available cores (4) in my arm64 target I modified the code:

```
void ScalarMultiply(ComplexInt16 *In, ComplexFloat *Ref, ComplexFloat *Out, uint32_t N)
{
    ComplexInt16 *pIn = In;
    ComplexFloat *pRef = Ref;
    ComplexFloat *pOut = Out;

    int16x4x2_t     VecIn;
    float32x4x2_t   VecRef;
    float32x4x2_t   VecRes;

    float32x4x2_t Res;
    int16x4_t ReIn, ImIn;
    float32x4_t ReRef, ImRef, ReInf32;
    float32x4_t ReRes, ImRes, ImInf32;
    uint32_t Offset;

#pragma omp parallel private (Offset, VecIn, VecRef, ReIn, ImIn, ReRef, ImRef, ReInf32, ImInf32, Res)
    {
    #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < N >> 2; i++)
        {
            Offset = i<<2;
            VecIn = vld2_s16((int16_t *)(pIn+ Offset));  //val[0]=1,3,5,7  val[1]=2,4,6,8 
            VecRef = vld2q_f32((float*)(pRef+ Offset));

            ReIn = VecIn.val[0];
            ImIn = VecIn.val[1];

            ReRef = VecRef.val[0];
            ImRef = VecRef.val[1];

            ReInf32 = vcvtq_f32_s32(vmovl_s16(ReIn));
            ImInf32 = vcvtq_f32_s32(vmovl_s16(ImIn));

            Res.val[0] = vsubq_f32(
                vmulq_f32(ReInf32, ReRef),
                vmulq_f32(ImInf32, ImRef));

            Res.val[1] = vaddq_f32(
                vmulq_f32(ImInf32, ReRef),
                vmulq_f32(ReInf32, ImRef));

            //Store in destination
            vst2q_f32((float*)(pOut+Offset), Res);

        }
    }
}
```

Before running the code I ran:

```bash
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
```

In my main code I checked the running time with:

```
#include "stdint.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "time.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "arm_neon.h"
#include <omp.h>

typedef struct ComplexInt16
{
    uint16_t Re;
    uint16_t Im;
}ComplexInt16;

typedef struct ComplexFloat
{
    float Re;
    float Im;
}ComplexFloat;

#define N_CELLS     1000000
#define N_REF       N_CELLS
#define ALIGN_SIZE  16

/********************************************************************/
void DisplayVectorFloat32x4(float32x4_t vec)
{
    //Etract uint32 from 4 uint32 vector
    printf("%f %f %f %f\n",
        vgetq_lane_f32(vec, 0),
        vgetq_lane_f32(vec, 1),
        vgetq_lane_f32(vec, 2),
        vgetq_lane_f32(vec, 3));
}

/********************************************************************/
void DisplayVectorInt16x4(int16x4_t vec)
{
    //Etract uint32 from 4 uint32 vector
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",
        vduph_lane_s16(vec, 0),
        vduph_lane_s16(vec, 1),
        vduph_lane_s16(vec, 2),
        vduph_lane_s16(vec, 3));
}

/**************************************************************************************************/
void ScalarMultiply(ComplexInt16 *In, ComplexFloat *Ref, ComplexFloat *Out, uint32_t N)
{
    ComplexInt16 *pIn = In;
    ComplexFloat *pRef = Ref;
    ComplexFloat *pOut = Out;

    int16x4x2_t     VecIn;
    float32x4x2_t   VecRef;
    float32x4x2_t   VecRes;

    float32x4x2_t Res;
    int16x4_t ReIn, ImIn;
    float32x4_t ReRef, ImRef, ReInf32;
    float32x4_t ReRes, ImRes, ImInf32;
    uint32_t Offset;

#pragma omp parallel private (Offset, VecIn, VecRef, ReIn, ImIn, ReRef, ImRef, ReInf32, ImInf32, Res)
    {
#pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < N >> 2; i++)
        {
            Offset = i << 2;
            VecIn = vld2_s16((int16_t *)(pIn + Offset));  //val[0]=1,3,5,7  val[1]=2,4,6,8 
            VecRef = vld2q_f32((float*)(pRef + Offset));

            ReIn = VecIn.val[0];
            ImIn = VecIn.val[1];

            ReRef = VecRef.val[0];
            ImRef = VecRef.val[1];

            ReInf32 = vcvtq_f32_s32(vmovl_s16(ReIn));
            ImInf32 = vcvtq_f32_s32(vmovl_s16(ImIn));

            Res.val[0] = vsubq_f32(
                vmulq_f32(ReInf32, ReRef),
                vmulq_f32(ImInf32, ImRef));

            Res.val[1] = vaddq_f32(
                vmulq_f32(ImInf32, ReRef),
                vmulq_f32(ReInf32, ImRef));

            //Store in destination
            vst2q_f32((float*)(pOut + Offset), Res);

            //pIn += 4;
            //pRef += 4;
            //pOut += 4;
        }
    }
}

/********************************************************************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timespec Before, After;
    ComplexInt16 *pIn = (ComplexInt16 *)aligned_alloc(ALIGN_SIZE, N_CELLS *sizeof(ComplexInt16));
    ComplexFloat *pRef = (ComplexFloat *)aligned_alloc(ALIGN_SIZE, N_REF*sizeof(ComplexFloat));
    ComplexFloat *pOut = (ComplexFloat *)aligned_alloc(ALIGN_SIZE, N_CELLS *sizeof(ComplexFloat));
    ComplexInt16 *pSrc = pIn;


    int Cnt = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_CELLS; i++)
    {
        pIn[i].Re = (Cnt);
        pIn[i].Im = (Cnt+1);
        Cnt += 2;
    }

    Cnt = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_REF; i++)
    {
        pRef[i].Re = Cnt;
        pRef[i].Im = Cnt + 1;
        Cnt += 2;
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &Before);

    ScalarMultiply(pSrc, pRef, pOut, N_REF);
    
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &After);
    uint32_t Elapsed = (After.tv_sec * 1E9 + After.tv_nsec) - (Before.tv_sec * 1E9 + Before.tv_nsec);
    printf("Multiply=%d\n", Elapsed);

    int rc;
    FILE *Handle;
    Handle = fopen("multiply.bin", "wb");
    if (Handle == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open %s\n", "multiply.bin");
        return -1;
    }

    rc = fwrite(pOut, 1, N_CELLS *sizeof(ComplexFloat), Handle);
    if (rc != N_CELLS *sizeof(ComplexFloat))
    {
        printf("Failed to write %s\n", "multiply.bin");
        return -1;
    }

    fclose(Handle);

    return 0;
}
```

```
TARGET=aarch64-linux-gnu
OBJS=Main.o

CFLAGS = -O2

LD = $(CC)
LIBS = -lstdc++ 
INCLUDES = 

multiply.out: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o multiply.out $(LIBS) -fopenmp 

Main.o: Main.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c Main.cpp -o Main.o -fopenmp 

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.out
```

But OpenMP runs run ~60% **slower** than the serial code.

Can you please tell what is wrong in the OpenMP code?

`ScalarMultiply` was compiled with `-O2 -fopenmp`
No code was optimized out because I checked the results by saving the output vector into a file.

Comment: You have data race conditions in your code. `Offset`, `VecIn`, `VecRef`, `ReIn`, `ImIn` , etc. should be private variables. You should check the sharing attributes of all of your variables and use your variables in their minimum required scope. How big is `N`?

Comment: Thank you for your commend. N=1000000. I modified the OpenMP code and specified the private variables. There was no performance improvement.

Comment: What processor/compiler do you use? Can you provide a [mre]? If so, we can try it on other systems.

Comment: Race condition like this should be easily spotted by just checking results. Correctness matters more than performance. Did you check results? Besides, why don"t you use the simpler `omp_get_wtime`? Additionally, what is the target processor and the binding to threads? (if the code is memory bound, it will not be faster).

Comment: The last code snippet contains cpp + Makefile. I really do not know what I changed. But now this code runs ~twice faster than the serial code.  with:  export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4. Do you think it can run even faster ?  It seems that when the input is much smaller (e.g 1000), running with OpenMP is much slower.

Comment: Since your output is collected in a common, continuous buffer I would initially guess that the performance issue is caused by [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). You can test this hypothesis by writing the output to separate buffers, or by leaving sufficient space inside your output buffer so that each core can write data without having to re-synchronise the cache between cores.

Comment: Please heed @Laci's comment: declare your variables in their minimum required scope. That's easier and better than declaring them outside that scope and having to specify private.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think there is significant false sharing: the code uses a `parallel for` which means that only the end points of the thread segments can be on conflicting cache lines.